# Что означает (?=) в регулярном выражении?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Есть такая регулярка:

```
new RegExp("^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W).*$", "g");
```

Что означает `"?="?`
Знаю, что `x(?=y)` находит x, только если за x следует y.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`(?=<pattern>)`** это positive look ahead означает, что строка соответствующая выражению до **`<pattern>`** считается попаданием, при этом строка **`<pattern>`** не будет захвачена или использована как совпадающая строка, например:

```
/\d+(?=M[bB])/ - при сравнении 1024MB совпадает 1024 и мы можем заменить это число не трогая обозначение MB или Mb.
```

отличие от not capturing в том, что в случае /\d+(?:M[bB])/ мы заменим всю строку, включая обозначение MB, capturing нужен, чтобы управлять группами захвата :) . например

```
"1024Mb added here".replace(/(\d+)(?:M[bB])?\s+(\w+).*$/,"$1Kb $2"); // "1024Kb added" - строка совпала и мы заменили обозначение на Kb   
"1024b added here".replace(/(\d+)(?:M[bB])?\s+(\w+).*$/,"$1Kb $2"); //"1024b added here" - строка не совпала вообще
"1024 added here".replace(/(\d+)(?:M[bB])?\s+(\w+).*$/,"$1Kb $2"); //"1024Kb added" строка совпала, и мы подписали Kb
```

---

По поводу вашего примера, там-же match наверняка, а он возвращает массив совпадений при  попадании, в вашем примере, если длина строки  8 или больше символов он вернет [""];

сравните

```
console.log("12345678".match(/^(?=.{8,})/)?true:false); //true
console.log("1234567".match(/^(?=.{8,})/)?true:false); //false
```

так-что смысл в таком выражении есть. то-же самое касается replace:

```
console.log("12345678".replace(/^(?=.{8,})/,"long! "));
console.log("1234567".replace(/^(?=.{8,})/,"long! "));
```

в последнем примере к началу строки добавляется "long! " если длина строки 8 символов или больше.

Answer (score 3):

Это и есть. 
Это положительная проверка справа.
Отрицательная проверка справа `(?!)`
Созданы для того чтобы узнавать окружение.

Comment: но в самом начале написано "^(?=.{8,})". Перед скобками ничего нет. Получается, что ищется ничто?)

Comment: ЕМНИП, это условие для всей регулярки.  В сочетании с ^ выглядит действительно довольно бессмысленно. С другой стороны, оно может и правда тут быть использовано по незнанию вместо ?: и успешно прокатывать, так как после ничего идет указанное выше, соответственно, противоречия нет.

Comment: ?: не годится, он действует  по-другому:

    console.log("12345678".replace(/^(?:.{8,})/,"long! "))